# swift - Initialize view controller from storyboard by overriding init

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, init

I have a ViewController instance defined in a storyboard. I can initialize it by the following

```
var myViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myViewControllerIdentifier") as! ViewController
```

Is there a way to override the init method of ViewController so that I can initialize it using

```
var myViewController = ViewController()
```

I tried overriding init

```
convenience init() {
    self = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SearchTableViewController") as! SearchTableViewController
}
```

but the compiler doesn't like that. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have a solution, but why would you want to do this?

Comment: It just looks cleaner I guess. Plus if the view is designed in a nib it works automatically so I can go from storyboards to nibs without changing the initialization code

Comment: How about just creating a custom ViewController class for each ViewController that you have? That seems a lot cleaner to me.

Comment: That's what I did so far. ViewController is a custom subclass, but I still have to initialize it using the storyboard

Comment: Just name it as the class of the Storyboard item and it's the same thing

Comment: encapsulation is a good thing, Caleb

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A convenience initializer must always delegate to a designated initializer for the same class, and a designated initializer must call a superclass initializer.

Since the superclass doesn't have an appropriate initializer, you would probably be better served by a class factory method:

```
static func instantiate() -> SearchTableViewController
{
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SearchTableViewController") as! SearchTableViewController
}
```

then use:

```
var myViewController = SearchTableViewController.instantiate()
```

Comment: according to the swift api guidelines - factory methods should begin with "make". https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/

Answer (score 15):

A class factory method is the way to go for now. Here's a protocol that you can use to quickly add `makeFromStoryboard` support to all `UIViewController`s.

```
protocol StoryboardInstantiable {

    static var storyboardName: String { get }
    static var storyboardBundle: NSBundle? { get }
    static var storyboardIdentifier: String? { get }
}
​
extension StoryboardInstantiable {

    static var storyboardBundle: NSBundle? { return nil }
    static var storyboardIdentifier: String? { return nil }

    static func makeFromStoryboard() -> Self {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: storyboardBundle)

        if let storyboardIdentifier = storyboardIdentifier {
            return storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(storyboardIdentifier) as! Self
        } else {
            return storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! Self
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
extension MasterViewController: StoryboardInstantiable {

    static var storyboardName: String { return "Main" }
    static var storyboardIdentifier: String? { return "Master" }
}
```

In case the view controller is the initial view controller in the storyboard, you can simply ignore `storyboardIdentifier`.

In case all the view controllers are in the same storyboard, you can also override `storyboardName` under the `StoryboardInstantiable` extension and return the name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Generics. Like this:

```
func Tvc<T>(_ vcType: T.Type) -> T {
    let vc = (vcType as! UIViewController.Type).vc//限制或明确为 UIViewController.Type
    return vc as! T
}

extension UIViewController {
    fileprivate static var vc: UIViewController {
        let M = UIStoryboard.init(name: "V", bundle: Bundle.main)
        return M.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "\(self)")
    }
}
```

Example

```
let vc = Tvc(HLCases.self)
_vc.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```