# Direct initializing of a viewController

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, viewcontroller

**My Desire Output:**

i want to pass data with direct initializing of a second viewController

in my first vc :

```
class MainViewController : UIViewController {

    @IBAction func nextQuestion(_ sender: UIButton ) {

        //enter code here
         questionIndex += 1
         let currentQuestion = exam1[questionIndex]
         questionLabel.text = currentQuestion.question
        //enter code here
        let svc = SecondViewController()
        svc.label.text = "some data from mainvc"  
}
```

in my secondvc :

```
class SecondViewController : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label : UILabel! 
}
```

// any error is not showed up when I write code an the simulator works. but when it comes to sending data to svc app crashes and gives error " found nil while unwrapping optional"

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821883/swift-initialize-view-controller-from-storyboard-by-overriding-init/31842625

Comment: because your `label` is `nil`.

Comment: But i defined it in the secondvc .

Comment: İf i define it as let labelText = label.text and give to labelText a string value. Does it work

Comment: So, after applying the solution I gave you, your next problem is that the view does not appear? Is that it?

Comment: After your solution there was error in the code as consecutive lines must be separated and it fixes last line of code SecondViewController()  as SecondViewController; () so it didnt make any sense :(

Comment: Sorry @SammHadji there was an error in the code I posted, now it is solved. My fault :P

Comment: thank you so much what you do for me. I realized it before and tried that but this time error is storyboard does not have vc with identifier SecondViewController but I have just one view controller how is that possible?

Comment: ok i solved it. but this time again "found nil while unwrapping an optinal"

Comment: I thinks label seems nil. but how can I assign a value to that label

Comment: İf use delegation method. Does it work with this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you do:

`let svc = SecondViewController()`

You are initializing without the information you put in the Storyboard (assuming you are using storyboards). Hence, so the UILabel is never initialized.

**Solution**

In order to solve that replace the line:

`let svc = SecondViewController()`

for

`let svc = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryboardName", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewIdentifier") as! SecondViewController`

Comment: If you have any problem finding the UIViewController indentifier let me know

Comment: When i wrote that code it gives  error as consecutive declarations on a line must be seperated. Because of SecondViewController() when it fixes SecondViewController;() and code doesnt work again. İ can not pass a single data to next vc. Why is that. İ van do it with segue. But i must do it without segue or connection between two vc

Comment: When a button is triggered i want to send data to next vc. But i dont wanna see the next vc because i want the button to do some other task and at the same time send data to next vc. İs that possible??

Comment: I have two viewcontrollers and tab bar controller and so there is no connection between vc. Just a simple quiz or exam app. When i pust next question button there comes next question's string it is ok. But when it comes to sending the answer data to next vc problem happens.

Comment: @SammHadji Answering your first comment. Yes, you have to replace `let svc = SecondViewController()` for the code I posted.

Comment: @SammHadji you will have to forgive me, but I don't really get your problem... Can you edit your question adding some more code to it? I will try to help you

Comment: I tried to edit it. as you see when button is trigerred next question comes. As this happens I want that button to send info to secondVc about which answer was chosen. and change the label's text in the second vc as chosen answer for example "A"